# Trying to scale image width/height based on window size while also centering image on page

Tags: html, css

Hey I'm not a programmer by any means just trying to hack my portfolio web site together to display some images. I would like the image on the page to be centered, but also scale down in size only (not up) based on the size of the window width/height.

I've been searching the forum all day and most of the examples are too confusing for me since I'm not a programmer. I was almost able to get the functionality with the below code, but the image is always attached to the top of the page which leaves a lot of ugly white space below it based on window size. Any help would be much appreciated, pretty much stuck at this point. Trying to achieve the functionality of this page when viewed in firefox before you click the zoom icon, but can't figure it out. http://www.tatianart.com/adriana_final_face_composite.jpg

in the css file

```
html { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width: 100%; }
body { margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:#171717; }
.wrapper { height:100%; width: 100%; padding-top:0%; padding-bottom:0px; text-align:center; background:#171717; }
.large_image { height:100%; width: 100%; }
.large_image img { max-height:100%; max-width:100%; width:auto; vertical-align:middle;}
```

my html page

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<main id="main" role="main" class="large_image">
<img src="joyrideturbo\test.jpg">
</main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your css with this:

```css
.wrapper {position: absolute; display: table; height:100%; width: 100%; padding-top:0%; padding-bottom:0px; text-align:center; background:#171717; }
.large_image {position: absolute; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; height:100%; width: 100%; }
.large_image img { max-height:100%; max-width:100%; width:auto;}
```

I'm letting the wrapper think it's a table, while main acts as a table-cell. This allows content to be centered vertically.

Comment: Hi Mouser, I gave that a try it fixes the centering of the image, but now the image no longer scales to fit the window. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Strange, it seems to make the image larger. With your CSS it renders perfect, but has bars. With mine it overflows.

Comment: Yes I'd like to avoid the overflow, but still get the centering.

Comment: @malcolm341 I've updated my code with `position: absolute` for `.wrapper` and `.large_image` this seems to do the trick. I saw that you also used position absolute on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after 4 hours of hacking around and trying different things I've got a partial solution. The image still doesn't scale down vertically, but all other functionality works and the image now centers correctly and looks correct in full screen. If anyone figures out how to get the image to shrink vertically as well please let me know.

html

```
<body>
<img src="joyrideturbo/test.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
</p>
</body>
```

css

```
html, body {background-color:#171717;}
body

img {
position: absolute;
top: -5px; bottom:0; left: 0; right:0;
margin: auto;
}

/*always show vertical scroll bar*/
html {overflow-y: scroll;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay finally got it! I'm posting a second answer because the above code actually creates a different affect where the image scales up to match the window size which might be desirable in certain situations. Any ways, finally got this working through trial and error. Image is centered and scales smaller/bigger when dragging window vertical/horizontal, only scales image up to max size of source art. Vertical scroll bar always present so their isn't a pop when transitioning from gallery page to full size image.

html

```
<body>
<div class="large_image">
<img src="joyrideturbo\test.jpg">
</div>
</body>
```

css

```
body { margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:#171717; }
.large_image img { 
max-height:100%;
max-width:100%;
width:auto;
position: absolute;
top: -5px; bottom:0; left: 0; right:0;
margin: auto;
}

/*always show vertical scroll bar*/
html {overflow-y: scroll;}
```